# Estimates on solution of pde

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let's consider the following pde in $\mathbb{R}^n$
$$\partial_t u=(i+\varepsilon)\Delta u,\,\,\,u(0,x)=u_0(x)$$
How to get the following estimate for its solution?
$$\Vert u\Vert_2\leq C_\varepsilon t^{-\frac{1}{4}}\Vert u_0\Vert_{\frac{3}{2}}$$
($\Vert f\Vert_p$ is the $L^p$ norm)

Comment: Convolution with fundamental solution + Young's convolution inequality?

Comment: @CareBear But how to get the factor $t^{-\frac{1}{4}}$?